# How to retrieve 20 or more twitter status with PHP?

Tags: php, twitter, status

This is my first time doing mobile development with twitter. I'm using Adobe Flash AS3 and PHP script to retrieve my own twitter status into my self made iphone application. However, Im unable to retrieve more than 20 statuses.

PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$name = $_GET['url'];
$url = 'http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=';
$url .= $name;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
ob_start();
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$string = ob_get_contents();
$content = ob_end_clean();
echo $string;
?>
```

In Flash CS5.5:

```
private static const USERNAME:String = "twitterusername";        
private static const URL:String = "http://myserverhost.com/proxy.php?url=";        
private static const REQUEST:String = URL + USERNAME;

urlLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.load(new URLRequest(REQUEST));
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, displayInfo);
```

I have given a read on twitter documentation([http://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines)) you gave me however Im still quite confused about "How to ask more than 20 statuses at a time". Is there any tutorial/sample code online for reference?

Comment: What don't you understand from the post?

Comment: I do not understand how do I use Count, max_id and since_id in my code above. May I know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
//use count parameter
$count = 30;
$url = "https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/screen_name.xml?count=".$count;
```

Comment: Hello, thank you! This works, but it does not contain any retweets? May I know how to use max_id and since_id in the code too?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking in the [manual](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline) for the method you are using, there will be a [count](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline#api-param-count) value that you can specify, max is 200.

So something like this

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?count=[count]&screen_name=[user]
```

Comment: Hi, the documentation says it will include retweets, but it does not include them. How do I use include_rts in the code?

Comment: No you need to set `include_rts=1` also. So everything will be something like this http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?include_rts=1&count=[count]&screen_name=[user]

Comment: @Zainu The only thing you need to do with all the arguments in the [manual](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline) is to add them to the url separated by a `&`